# reorder sort_order in table with sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this table:

```
id  sort_ord
0   6
1   7
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   8
```

Why does this query:

```
UPDATE table
  SET sort_ord=(
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM table AS pq
    WHERE sort_ord<table.sort_ord
    ORDER BY sort_ord
  )
WHERE(sort_ord>=0)
```

Produce:

```
id  sort_ord
0   4
1   5
2   0
3   1
4   2
5   4
6   6
```

I was expecting all `sort_ord` fields to subtract by 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is defined: https://www.sqlite.org/isolation.html

About this link i can interpret, you has several instances for one query (update table and select count table) and independent of each other.
When you are in update sort_data(5) id 5, you have new data for read on every "SET sot_ord" (understanding what say about isolation), and now the result is 4.
Every select is a new instance and a new data reading

```
id  sort_ord
0   4
1   5
2   0
3   1
4   2
5   5**
6   8**
```